# Problem with jquery .submit() and variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure what to do and why it is not working it is my first attempt at something like this.

Here is a fiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/ProjectV1/LVPtN/

You will notice in javascript I have a var error which is by default false.

If there is an error it is true.

I have displayed the value of error next to each input on my form.

If the variable error is false it should submit the form and false it shouldn't.

The problem arises when an error occurs, and is then corrected the form will not submit.

Look at the fiddle. The form directs to google just for testing.

Comment: I think you need to make an associative array with an element for each input you want to check for errors on. Then when the submit event is executed, you can loop over the array looking to see which inputs are in an error state. If any are, prevent the submit from completing.

Comment: Ok am trying this now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the issue is with the `error` being inside the function which will be called on blur. And when the function call is done, it goes undefined. The deal is that the variable should be global. You will need to put this above the `$(document).ready()` This should work:

```
var error = false;

$('#joinForm input').blur(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (id == 'email') {
        $('#emailMsg').hide();
        if (val == '') {
            error = true;
            $('#' + id).after('<div id="emailMsg" class="error">' + error + '</div>');
        }
        else {
            $('#' + id).after('<div id="emailMsg" class="success">' + error + '</div>');
        }
    }
    if (id == 'cemail') {
        $('#cemailMsg').hide();
    }
    if (id == 'password') {
        $('#passwordMsg').hide();
        if (val == '') {
            error = true;
            $('#' + id).after('<div id="passwordMsg" class="error">' + error + '</div>');
        }
        else {
            $('#' + id).after('<div id="passwordMsg" class="success">' + error + '</div>');
        }
    }
    if (id == 'cpassword') {
        $('#cpasswordMsg').hide();
    }
    if (id == 'username') {
        $('#usernameMsg').hide();
        if (val == '') {
            error = true;
            $('#' + id).after('<div id="usernameMsg" class="error">' + error + '</div>');
        }
        else {
            $('#' + id).after('<div id="usernameMsg" class="success">' + error + '</div>');
        }
    }
    $('#joinForm').submit(function(){
        if (error == true) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok after I tried your idea, I realised that it would always be true if an error had occured before as the variable wasn't set in the function. So I updated it so that error = false; in all the success states and it now works with the variable declared outside the function with a value of null... Thanks for your input.

Comment: According to me, the validation needs to be put into a different function which returns true or false. And on the blur, call this function to update the error variable. In the validate() function, keep a temp variable which says true initially and if anything goes false, it should keep on going but not allow any other field validation to update its value from false to true. In the end return the state of temp variable.